# The application failed to initialize properly(0xc0150002)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I am trying to identify memory leaks in an application; I'm using visual leak detector on vs2008. The application compiles fine but upon runtime is giving this error. I've placed vld_x86.dll in my executable directory(Debug build directory) as required but with no success.

Comment: Try parent directory of `Debug`. From memory, I think the working directory is not `Debug` but its parent.

Comment: I've placed the .dll in all directories(Debug, Release and parent) and it still crashes.

Comment: Are your sure your app is 32-bit? Does `vld_x86.dll` have any dependencies?

Comment: Yes, the app is 32-bit. That .dll's documentation can be found here: http://vld.codeplex.com/

Comment: It is an install problem, usually a missing dependency.  Look in the Windows event log for a detailed diagnostic of this error.

Comment: Make sure to also copy Microsoft.DTfW.DHL.manifest into your debug directory